# Attempt to add values to Array causes app to spin into an endless loop

Tags: javascript

for some sick reason, my check productIDs[addIndex] = allProductIDs[lastProductFoundIndex + i]; causes my app to spin into an infinite loop:

numberOfImagesToDisplay is set to 4

```
if (state == "next")
{
    for(var a = 0; a < numberOfImagesToDisplay; a++) {
        alert("a=" + a + ", numImages=" + numberOfImagesToDisplay)

        if (a > 0) { addIndex = productIDs.length + 1; }
        alert("I'm in GetNextProductIDs() 1");
        //var lastProductFoundIndex = $.inArray(lastProductID, allProductIDs);
        //alert("I'm in GetNextProductIDs() 2");

        if (lastProductIndex >= 0) {
            alert("I'm in GetNextProductIDs() 3");
            //productIDs[addIndex] = allProductIDs[lastProductFoundIndex + i];
        }
    }
}
```

If I take out that line, it moves on.

**Update**: Resolved. `lastProductIndex` was not defined. So what was happening is that it would get there and the loop would end but it's weird because a callback was being called again when it should have ended. So that callback method kept calling this method and this method would end at that spot, the callback method would again be called, and so you had an endless loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "spin into an infinite loop"? In a debugger, what is it doing? Does it simply not return? Is it possible that an invalid index is causing the function to throw an exception?

Comment: You've GOT to add more code and remove the bugs.  The for loop doesn't even work (initializes a, but increments i). lastProductIndex isn't defined anywhere in this snippet, etc.

Comment: You have been posting one question after the other trying to solve one problem. Try to post the whole code, explain what you are trying to do so that it's easier for everyone involved.

Comment: I tried to get a test case going on this, but after the 3rd "variable not defined" error I gave up trying.  Fix the bugs - give us a test snippet that will actually execute - and then we'll see about your actual problem.

Comment: Peter, that would require you to setup and download a jQuery plug-in, much more than just setting up a snippet.

Comment: Resolved.  lastProductIndex was not defined.  So what was happening is that it would get there and the loop would end but it's weird because a callback was being called again when it should have ended.  So that callback method kept calling this method and this method would end at that spot, the callback method would again be called, and so you had an endless loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very strange. All I can think is that you have an `onpropertychange` event firing that also modifies `i`. Major longshot, I know.

What if you add the `var` keyword to your `for` loop? That would turn it into a local variable instead of a global variable so no other function could inadvertantly trash your loop index.

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfImagesToDisplay; i++)
```

Note: You should have the `var` there whether or not that's the problem.

**Update:** What does `alert("i="+i+", numImages="+numberOfImagesToDisplay)` display each iteration through your loop? Do those variables have the expected values?

Are you sure *this* loop is stuck? Maybe it's another loop. Could it be that you're re-entering this loop repeatedly thereby getting repeated alerts? I just don't see how that line could cause this loop to become an infinite loop.

Comment: var made no difference.  Again if I remove this line, all is fine and it exits my function just fine: productIDs[addIndex] = allProductIDs[lastProductFoundIndex + i];

Comment: weird, I get 0 and 4 every time.  wtf

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you incrementing variable `a` in there anywhere, but you're incrementing a variable `i` in your loop. `a` will therefore always be 0 -

```
for(var a = 0; a < numberOfImagesToDisplay; i++)
```

Comment: I had updated the original post...supposed to be an a, and a is what I have in my code.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to your suspected problem line, but, at the line

```
for(var a = 0; a < numberOfImagesToDisplay; i++)
```

your setting *a = 0* and the loop will run while *a < numberOfImagesToDisplay*. I dont see anywhere where you are incrementing or changing *a* to exit the for loop.